# How to find objects without UVs?

Tags: uv, objects, selection-tools, outliner

I have a scene with hundreds of objects and even if I started by unwrapping multiple objects groups at once and packed them in the same tiles, sometimes there are parts that I fail to select. 
Is there a way to identify or select the objects left without UV? 
Ideally I'd look for a filter in Outliner but I don't see it. Blender 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben Morrison offered this solution (specific to blender2.80) for selecting objects that don't have UV [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-find-objects-without-uv/1146229?u=bestelix). If you know other solutions not involving scripts I'd like to know them.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
mesh_objects = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']
for o in mesh_objects:
    if not o.data.uv_layers:
        o.select_set(True)
```